# How to access per project / per preset configuration data in vue-cli 3.x?

Tags: plugins, vue.js, configuration, vue-cli

I'm looking to create a vue-cli 3.x plugin that generates extra files in the project when invoked and templates these based on configuration info entered by the user.

It's rather easy to collect this information from user prompts but it'd be much nicer if users could put this info into some sort of configuration file and have the plugin read it from there.

I understand vue-cli now uses a `vue.config.js` file on the project level and `~/.vuerc` on a more global (preset) level. However, it doesn't look like my generator function would have access to either one of those files.

"The **entire preset**" should be passed as the third argument to the function when invoking the plugin with `module.exports = (api, options, rootOptions) => {}` in `./generator/index.js`, `rootOptions` is `undefined`.

Sililarly, the use of `vue.config.js` is discussed in the documentation when talking about **service plugins**, but there's no mention how to use it in a generator function.

Am I missing something obvious here or is there really no officially sanctioned way to do this? Nothing stops me from reading `vue.config.js` in my function, but this feels hacky. And I wouldn't even know how to find out which preset was used to create the project.

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that you can't find ~/.vuerc?
I had the same issue and I found the solution [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1506).
The solution is to use the command line

> vue config

to see .vuerc, and then use

> vue config --delete presets.yourPresetName

to delete your preset. 
As well, if you can't type in your preset name in the terminal because it contains a space or an apostrophe, you can use

> vue config --edit

to open .vuerc with a text editor and just edit it there